Excel: mark/format lines that have changed in past week
In our department we have a weekly team meeting.
To follow up the topics that need to be discussed, we use an Excel table (with automatic filtering and sorting).
I already have a system voor new topics from the current week before the meeting: =IF([@[Datum reg]]>=TODAY()-7,1,0)
If the result = 1; I apply a conditional formating to that line.
In addition these lines get sorted to be on top of the list.
To avoid that we have to go through the entire list every week, I'm trying to find a way to mark the existings lines (from previous weeks) that will make it to the meeting.
I was thinking about using checkboxes but am still waiting for the release of the new checkbox feature, that has been announced in fall of 2023.
I know that you can use the Development tab to insert these, but that places the checkbox on top of a cell (the new feature should place it in a cell) - so for now I don't want to put to much effort in it.
I want to avoid using VBA or macro's, since these don't run well due to our rather strickt cybersecurity.
